# azure durable function triggers without reason

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I started using Durable Functions and my workflow works correctly, but time to time, one of my functions continues to be triggered and ruins all my outputs. I guess this function is triggered because failed few days ago when I started using durable functions.

I tried to purge/delete all history, but the functions still triggers every time I restart my app... Last time I called my orchestrator was 2 days ago, but this function still shows up without any reason...

That's how I deleted/purged all history

```
            var createdTimeFrom = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-365);
            var createdTimeTo = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(12);
            var runtimeStatus = new List<OrchestrationStatus>
            {
                OrchestrationStatus.Completed,
                OrchestrationStatus.Failed,
                OrchestrationStatus.Terminated,
                OrchestrationStatus.Running,
                OrchestrationStatus.ContinuedAsNew,
                OrchestrationStatus.Pending,
                OrchestrationStatus.Canceled
            };
            var result = await orchestrationClient.PurgeInstanceHistoryAsync(createdTimeFrom, createdTimeTo, runtimeStatus);
            log.LogInformation("Scheduled cleanup done, {InstancesDeleted} instances deleted", result.InstancesDeleted);
```

and these are the results & the logs about the strange `archive` function that still triggers time to time without being called by me...

```
[2022-06-14T20:22:00.343Z] Executing 'CleanupOldWorkflows' (Reason='Timer fired at 2022-06-14T23:22:00.0281404+03:00', Id=49acc185-6780-4b2c-9d33-b5acabada7f9)
[2022-06-14T20:22:17.747Z] Scheduled cleanup done, 49 instances deleted
[2022-06-14T20:22:17.772Z] Executed 'CleanupOldWorkflows' (Succeeded, Id=49acc185-6780-4b2c-9d33-b5acabada7f9, Duration=17729ms)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.094Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=4c9852e6-238a-4337-a603-aa16e2e083dd)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.139Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=1fcdc522-479f-44f8-8b88-0627916dd896)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.197Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=d65cb7fd-55f5-41a7-85a8-176f41922865)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.264Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=8ff863d3-0844-490e-8f87-801ade7b68e8)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.326Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=04cde2b7-d6aa-42d9-b745-ba6cb3c47118)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.386Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=1fd3921b-ca99-4d45-a3af-fc6c8633279b)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.447Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=727c3c70-5b96-4e03-8198-76cd38a2f751)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.509Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=f0cdbf00-0636-4391-ab93-0984667046f9)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.568Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=6d9b9aa1-227c-4ada-b7ac-05594dc244ed)
[2022-06-14T20:23:02.638Z] Executing 'archive' (Reason='(null)', Id=8bfb3c7c-8fa3-42ce-95c8-bcb7cfd31e43)
[2022-06-14T20:23:28.987Z] Executed 'archive' (Succeeded, Id=f0cdbf00-0636-4391-ab93-0984667046f9, Duration=26485ms)
```

How is that even possible if I deleted all the history of my durable functions?

Comment: Hey @johnykes, I just reproduced the same in my local as it's working like expected.
Please share your full Durable Function code.

Comment: @RajkumarPalnati-MT My code wasn't triggered in the past few days and I have no other kind of triggers except HTTP. The orchestrator triggers itself because failed few days ago. The problem is that the Azure Storage still has some wrong history data which is not properly deleted/purged.

Answer (score 0):

> How is that even possible if I deleted all the history of my durable functions?

This line of code returns the deleted instance  `await starter.PurgeInstanceHistoryAsync(createdTimeFrom, creattimeto, runtimeStatus);`

Get the Status of Instance an [Orchestration instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#get-all-instances-status)

I reproduce the `Durable Functions` it's running as expected.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DurableTask.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AzureFurableTriggersWithoutReason
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            //Task<PurgeHistoryResult> purgeHistoryResult(createdTimeFrom, creattimeto,IEnumerable<OrchestrationStatus> runtimestatus)
            var outputs = new List<string>();
             
            // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "London"));
          
            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_Hello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            var createdTimeFrom = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-365);
            var creattimeto = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(12);
            var runtimeStatus = new List<OrchestrationStatus>
            {
                OrchestrationStatus.Completed,
                OrchestrationStatus.Failed,
                OrchestrationStatus.Terminated,
                OrchestrationStatus.Running,
                OrchestrationStatus.ContinuedAsNew,
                OrchestrationStatus.Pending,
                OrchestrationStatus.Canceled
            };

            var result = await starter.PurgeInstanceHistoryAsync(createdTimeFrom, creattimeto, runtimeStatus);
            log.LogInformation($"Scheduled Cleanup done= '{instanceId}'.", result.InstancesDeleted);

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

If this `purgeInstanceHistoryAsync` method is not being used, so your instances will be remains in history.

[image]

Second time execution, it will show 1 Instance Deleted.
[image]

Comment: Of course it's running as expected. My code is running as expected as well. The problem is that the history is not purged/deleted completely and my `archive` function is still triggered time to time because of that Azure bug.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: I renamed my `archive` function into something else (`archiveFiles`) and the function is not triggered anymore. I'm 100% sure this is an Azure bug and the history is not completely purged/deleted.